# Probability on sample method sending messages with a ruby Telegram bot

Tags: ruby, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a Telegram inline bot written with ruby. I want to have more control on what it answers and *to shut it up* sometimes, even if it *should* reply.

This is what I have now:

```
when /WHATEVER/
  whatever = ['option 1', 'option 2']
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "#{whatever.sample}")
```

I want it to reply 50% of the time with Option 1, 30% with Option 2 and 20% not to answer.

Is it possible?

Sorry If didn't explain correctly, I'm not a programmer and English is not my first language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random number and use it to decide what action to take:

```
r = rand # 0.0 <= r < 1
if r <= 0.5 
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "option 1")
else if r <= 0.8 
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: "option 2")
else
  # do nothing, you can actually ommit the `else` clause
end
```

A less elegant way:

```
options = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", nil, nil]
option = options.sample
bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: option) if option
```